# Find all words in binary buffer using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I want to find in **binary buffer** (`bytes`) all the "words" build from ascii lowercase and digits that **only** 5 chars length.

For example:

`bytes(b'a\x1109ertx01\x03a54bb\x05')` contains `a54bb` and `09ert`  .

Note the string `abcdef121212` is larger than 5 chars so I don't want it

I have build that set

```
set([ord(i) for i in string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits])
```

What is the fastest way to do that using Python?

Comment: what's your "binary buffer" contents?

Comment: just as an aside, `set([i for i in string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits])` is an unecessarily complicated way of doing `set(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)`

Comment: Sorry, why does it contain `09ert`? The word wouldn't be `09ertx01` and thus longer than exactly 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My instinct would be to just go with regex here:

```
>>> import re
>>> buffer = b'a\x1109ertx01\x03a54bb\x05'
>>> re.findall(b"[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}", buffer)
[b'09ert', b'a54bb']
```

EDIT:

After your clarification, I would try just doing:

```
re.findall(b"[a-zA-Z0-9]+", buffer)
```

And then filtering for bytes of exactly length 5, so:

```
[x for x in re.findall(b"[a-zA-Z0-9]+", buffer) if len(x) == 5]
```

Comment: Isn't REGEX a relatively slow solution for searching in a large buffer?

Comment: @vtable for this type of pattern compared to something you would write in Python? My intuition says not really, but feel free to profile it. What's "large" in this case?